# Jquery id change .attr won't fully work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I've got a div (which I turned in a button with `.click`) with the Id of knight.
Whenever I press ANY of the 3 buttons (including knight) it changes the id of knight to elf (yeah I'm making a game).
I've got a `.hover` for knight, as follows:

```
$('#knight').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
```

That works, whenever I load the page it changes to green when I hover over it and back to blue when I get off.

Change id script.

```
    $('.submenu').click(function (e){
    $('#knight').attr('id', 'elf').text('Elf');
    });
```

When I press any of the buttons (submenu) the text changes to 'Elf' and the color becomes the one in the css with id #elf

css

```
#knight{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

#elf{
    background-color: #00FF00;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

So I assume that when I hover over it after id change it takes the following code:

```
    $('#elf').hover(
function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#01DF01');
},
function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#00FF00');
});
```

Instead of becoming different colors of green, it becomes green and blue again. It's like after taking css traits it resets the id back to #knight.

Can someone help me?

Edit #1

I forgot to show the div id knight which is the actual button with .click function

```
<div id="text">
<div id="story">Choose a class.</div>
<div class="submenu" id="knight">Knight</div>
```

That's where the `$('.submenu`).click function comes in.
Also if someone knows another way of removing text and these buttons and make new ones if you click on one please tell me. I knew I forgot to add something.

Comment: Changing id does not remove events that are already attached and will not bind events.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nice first question. You've provided expected behavior, actual behavior, and only the relevant code. Well done!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use classes instead of id ? I'm not sure modifying an ID is supported.

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq there are no problems with modifying element's ID.

Comment: @charlietfl how do I call it after the change?

Comment: generally a bad idea to change the id in the first place. Better to toggle a class and check for that class in your event handlers

Comment: Even if it is possible to change an id, I also think it's better to toggle classes. That way the call to hover() would not be necessary.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fy3s917w/) is what is all about, I suppose.

Comment: And proper solution with classes and CSS: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fy3s917w/1/).

Comment: @Regent you should throw up your answer, it's the best solution by far

Answer (score 2):

As you are making a game, I assume your actual code has more going on in your event handlers. If this is the case, the below method would work using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and using `classes` instead of `ids`.

If the effects/actions you are wanting can all be achieved with CSS, regent's solution at https://jsfiddle.net/fy3s917w/1 is actually much better

```js
// bind a function to an element (#container) that contains the elements we want to affect 
// you could also bind to document but it's better to bind to an element closser to the targets
// the handler will listen for events on the container's descendants that match the selectors provided (.knight and .elf)
$("#container").on('mouseover', '.knight, .elf', function() {
  // change the css for both classes, this just stops us from having to have 2 separate functions, only one element will exist at a time on the actual page
  $(".knight").css('background-color', 'green');
  $(".elf").css('background-color', '#01DF01');
});
// same thing here but for the mouseout event
$("#container").on('mouseout', '.knight, .elf', function() {
  $(".knight").css('background-color', 'blue');
  $(".elf").css('background-color', '#00FF00');
});
// when the button is clicked, use `toggleClass` to remove the 'knight' class and add the 'elf' class
// i've added `.css('background-color', '#00FF00')` to the end because web-kit browsers wont redraw the element and update the style when we change a class if the style was originally set with `.css()`
$('.submenu').click(function(e) {
  $('.knight').toggleClass( 'knight, elf' ).text('Elf').css('background-color', '#00FF00');
});
```

```css
.knight {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 20px;
      width: 100px;
    }
.elf {
      background-color: #00FF00;
      height: 20px;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="knight"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="submenu" value="change unit type" />
```

Comment: @Regent yep, I had it there when I tried something else and forgot to remove it, thanks

Comment: Your code is triggering hover events for both elements at once, so hovering over a single element will change background-color of both, that does not seem like what OP wants.

Comment: @deolectrix look closer, there is only one element. It calls the change on both just to keep the code shorter but only one element exists at a time.  Regent's method in the comments above is better, but this is also perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I'm new to jquery so this solution needs to sink in. I'll rate this solution once I understand the code.

Comment: @Impervox i'll add some comments to explain my code but regent's solution at http://jsfiddle.net/fy3s917w/1/ is actually much better

Comment: @DelightedD0D I apologise, you are right about that, I was thinking of two different elements - guess it would help to actually run your example...;)

Comment: @Impervox updated, also check out the link I posted for event delegation, you will deffinately run into places where you will need this in the future, but as I said, regent's solution is actually better than mine : )

Comment: @DelightedD0D that might work. However I forgot to say that the div knight is my button with a .click function. I knew I forgot something. I'll edit the question and add the button itself in there. Also if there is another way of removing the old text and buttons and add new text and new buttons I'd like to know.

Comment: @DelightedD0D it works, thanks. Now how do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: @Impervox Click the checkmark near the top left of the answer that best solved your problem, see http://prntscr.com/6xkezi

Answer (score 0):

use `('#knight').off('hover')` in the click event before changing the id to remove the old hover event. Also bind the new hover also in the click event after changing the id.
More info: [jQuery/off](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 0):

it's doing exactly what you asked it to do.  you have bound the function to the on click of the "submenu" div itself.  not to any element within it.

try changing to

```
$('#kinght').click(function (e){
  $( this ).attr('id', 'elf').text('Elf');
});
```

Comment: I did indeedbound it to submenu. But all 3 buttons are in a div submenu. Doesn't that mean it does the same for all 3 buttons?

Comment: it means that it's applied to the whole area that submenu covers, which covers everything that is nested within it - think of it like drawing two boxes on a sheet of paper, and you want someone to tell you when a thrown paperclip  lands in one of the boxes, but what you actually tell them to do is tell you whenever a paperclip lands on the paper.  You'll still here about all the paperclips that end up in the box, but you'll also here about every one that misses the box yet still lands on the paper.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is removing the hover you made with jQuery and make it with CSS

```
#knight {
  background-color: blue;
}
#knight:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

After, as you're making a game, you may want to keep the jQuery client side to make the hover effect.
The problem is that when you call `$('#knight').hover(...);`, you add an hover function to #knight, witch is then associated with it.

Even if you change the ID, it keep the function you gave it when the page loaded.

Instead of just changing the ID, you should consider to remove every event associated with the old button, and creating a new .hover event.

Comment: I also need the improvised button to be clickable. Since .hover isn't working I don't think .click will. So this wouldn't solve my problem.